# Cannot run program file:/runtime.jar!/some_binary: error=2, No such file or directory (Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin

i am working on a kotlin project and in my task i have to execute binary from code using ProcessBuilder.
i copied this binary to resources, tested my code and everything worked good locally.

```kotlin
val url = ConversionTool::class.java.classLoader.getResource("my_binary_file_name")
url!! //ensure that file exists, just for test
val process = ProcessBuilder(url.path).start()
```

But when i deploy this code to docker testing environment, i get following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "file:/runtime.jar!/my_binary_file_name": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
```

Why is this happening? I made sure that `my_binary_file_name` exists in runtime.jar in container and `url` variable is not null.

Answer (score 1):

The "file" is inside the ziü file `runtime.jar`. Its **URL** is `jar:file:/...`. So first the `jar:` protocol. In Java `File` is a file on the disk, and the generalization `Path` can also be a file inside a zip or an URL, or some custom file system like for LDAP or whatever.

However with `Process` from the `ProcessBuilder` you are again one the operating system level. There is no `jar:` URL handler, just `file:`, `html:`, `mailto:` and such.

However you can copy the Path from the URL to a temporary file, and execute that, using [`Files#createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)).

```
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
Path file = Files.createTempFile'(...);
Files.copy(path, file);
```

Windows has the feature of zip folders, so you might try to name the jar as `.zip` (and use `"file: ... runtime.zip/ ..."`. But I have no experience with that.

Comment: There's no `Paths.get(url)` and `Paths.get(url.toURI())` is likely to result in FileSystemNotFoundException.

Comment: @k314159 toURI is needed. `"jar:file: ... .jar! ..."` gives a valid Path with a jar file system view. And one can copy that path to an other filesystem, like that of a temporary file. One cannot use it in a Process though.

Comment: I think this work in JDK 1.8, but for Java 9+ will require a command-line option to load module jdk.zipfs.

Comment: @k314159 **jdk.zipfs** good to know

Comment: btw Files.createTempFile creates a file with no execute permissions by default (just rw-------)

Comment: i just ended up copying executable to root in Dockerfile and giving right permissions there.